# Nginx does not host other pages than index.html

Tags: nginx

I've set up Nginx and I'm able to host the index page, the index page contains links to other pages in the same directory, but when you go through the links you get a 404 not found error, in the address bar it has the correct path.

Is the something else in the Nginx sites-enabled default file I'm supposed to change?

Comment: Your question is [off-topic in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: Ah, my bad. Thanks for the info, should I delete the post?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess you have the option to move it. If not, just delete and post it on  one of the other forums.

Comment: When you post this on Unix & Linux or Superuser, you should include relevant parts of your Nginx configuration. It will be difficult to answer the question otherwise.